# How to change wired data list after get data from imperative apex method

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a variable 'contactList' wired to an apex method which will return a list of contact. There is another imperative method will return a list of contact filtered by 'Name' field. 
The contact list rendered well after the page init, but after I change the value of 'contactList' by JS, the frontend page didn't display the record list retrieved from apex method.
[image: Firsr Load]
After click search button the list changed to below, but the contactList are not empty.
[image: After search]
Below is code snippet of the code.

```html
    --------------------contactList.html----------------------
    <template>
        <lightning-card>
            <div style="display: inline-block" slot='actions'>
                <lightning-button label="Search" onclick={searchRecords}></lightning-button>
                <lightning-input data-id='searchInputId' style="display: inherit" placeholder='Search By Name' onchange={changeSearchValue} value={searchValue}></lightning-input>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <lightning-button label="New" onclick={showForm}></lightning-button>
            </div>
            <template for:each={contactList.data} for:item='contact' for:index='itemindex'>
                <c-custom-contact-list-item key={contact.Id} contact={contact} if-check={checkAllVar} item-index={itemindex} onitemchecked={modifySelectedList}></c-custom-contact-list-item>
            </template>
        </lightning-card>
    </template>
```

```
    ------------------contactList.js----------------------
    import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
    import getContactList from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getContactList';
    import findContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.findContacts';
    import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent'

    export default class ContactList extends LightningElement {
        @wire(getContactList) contactList;
        searchValue = '';

        showForm(){
            let modalIten = this.template.querySelector('section.slds-modal');
            modalIten.classList.add('showModel');
        }

        changeSearchValue(event){
            //console.log(this.searchValue);
            this.searchValue = event.target.value;
        }

        searchRecords(){
            console.log(this.searchValue);
            findContacts({searchKey : this.searchValue}).then(result => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));  // After called this method, the returned value will overwrite this.contactList;
                this.contactList = result;
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            this.template.querySelector('[data-id="searchInputId"]').value = null;
            this.searchValue = null;
        }
    }
```

```html
    --------------------customContactListItem.html-------------------
    <template>
        <lightning-layout class='list-line'>
            <lightning-layout-item class='slds-truncate' style="width: 3.3333333333%" >
                <lightning-input type='checkbox' variant='label-hidden' class="listCheckbox" checked={changeCheck} onchange={handleCheck}></lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item class='slds-truncate slds-size_1-of-6 slds-text-align_center'>
                <a onclick={openDetail}>{contact.Name}</a>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item class='slds-truncate slds-size_1-of-6 slds-text-align_center'>
                {contact.Phone}
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item class='slds-truncate slds-size_1-of-6 slds-text-align_center'>
                {contact.Email}
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item class='slds-truncate slds-size_1-of-6 slds-text-align_center'>
                {contact.Title}
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item class='slds-truncate slds-size_1-of-6 slds-text-align_center'>
                <img src={contact.Picture__c} width="25px" height="25px"></img>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </template>
```

```
    ---------------------------------ContactController.cls------------------------------
    public with sharing class ContactController {

        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static List<Contact> getContactList() {
            return [SELECT Id, Name, Title, Phone, Email, Picture__c FROM Contact WHERE Picture__c != null LIMIT 10];
        }

        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static List<Contact> findContacts(String searchKey) {
            String key = '%' + searchKey + '%';
            List<Contact> list_con = [SELECT Id, Name, Title, Phone, Email, Picture__c FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE :key AND Picture__c != null LIMIT 10];
            System.debug(searchKey);
            System.debug(list_con);
            return list_con;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your console log:

So a wire response in JSON format looks something like

`{ "data" : [Your response]}`

Now, imperative method response looks like

`[ {Your response} ,{Your response}]`

In your `searchRecords()` method you are just populating just this.contactList

The markup template:for is expecting the `data` in data attribute.
`<template for:each={contactList.data}`

In your `searchRecords()` method you are just populating just `this.contactList`, not the data attribute of `this.contactList`

```
searchRecords(){
        console.log(this.searchValue);
        findContacts({searchKey : this.searchValue}).then(result => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));  // After called this method, the returned value will overwrite this.contactList;
            this.contactList = {};
            this.contactList.data = result;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: This answer perfectly solved my problem after I add '.data' behind this.contactList. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is because, wired service always returns an object to property of function in the data structure `{data:some_result,error:some_error}`.

But imperative method promise will resolve to exactlky whatever you are returning from Apex method.

So, initially as you are referring to `contactList.data`, its loading but later when you are searching through `findContacts`, you are over-writing it with array in which there is no `data`.

**IMPORTANT:**

I would recommend to use below where you just need `findContacts`. Wired service will fetch the data again whenever there is change in dynamic property `'$searchKey'`.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import findContacts from '@salesforce/apex/poc.findContacts';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent'

export default class ContactList extends LightningElement {
    searchKey = '';
    @wire(findContacts, { searchKey: '$searchKey' }) contactList;

    showForm() {
        let modalIten = this.template.querySelector('section.slds-modal');
        modalIten.classList.add('showModel');
    }

    changeSearchValue(event) {
        //console.log(this.searchValue);
        this.searchValue = event.target.value;
    }

    searchRecords() {
        console.log(this.searchValue);
        this.searchKey = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="searchInputId"]').value;
        this.template.querySelector('[data-id="searchInputId"]').value = null;
        this.searchValue = null;
    }
}
```

There is no need `getContactList`. Also whenever `searchKey` changes, wire will re-fetch the results.